# Selecting max(date) twice from the same table, for different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

This is a small snippet of my table, which currently contains ~10,000,000 rows

```
+---------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
| card_id | date                | avg_price | foil_avg_price |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
|   10000 | 2014-06-28 09:05:56 |      5.02 |          10.22 |
|   20000 | 2014-06-28 09:05:54 |     14.58 |          25.10 |
|   10000 | 2014-06-29 09:05:56 |      0.00 |          19.62 |
|   20000 | 2014-06-29 09:05:54 |     14.58 |          0.00  |
|   10000 | 2014-07-01 09:05:56 |      0.00 |          19.62 |
|   20000 | 2014-07-01 09:05:54 |      0.00 |          25.10 |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

It is a price history for cards, including what the avg_price and what the foil_avg_price was for each day or so.

I'd like to select, for a group of card id's the most recent date when the foil_avg_price was > 0, what that price was, and the most recent date that the avg_price was > 0, and what that price was.  My resulting data set for the above would look something like this:

```
+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------------+
| card_id | avg_date            | avg_price | foil_date           | foil_avg_price |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------------+
|   10000 | 2014-06-28 09:05:56 |      5.02 | 2014-07-01 09:05:54 |          19.62 |
|   20000 | 2014-06-29 09:05:54 |     14.58 | 2014-07-01 09:05:54 |          25.10 |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------------+
```

I'm sure that this involves an INNER JOIN on the same table but I can't quite get my head around it.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Three steps:

- Find last price date
- Find last foil price date
- resolve prices on these dates

So,

```
SELECT dates.*, price.avg_price, foilprice.foil_avg_price 
FROM (
    SELECT 
      card_id,
      MAX(IF(avg_price>0, `date`, '0001-01-01')) AS avg_date,
      MAX(IF(foil_avg_price>0, `date`, '0001-01-01')) AS foil_avg_date
    FROM card_price
    GROUP BY card_id
  ) AS dates
  INNER JOIN card_price AS price
    ON dates.card_id=price.`date`
  INNER JOIN card_price AS foilprice
    ON dates.card_id=foilprice.`date`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Correct me if I'm wrong but won't the LIMIT 1 on the first sub select prevent this query from ever returning more than one row?  I need to return this data for a group of card ids, e.g. card_id in (10000,20000,...)

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood your question - I thought you want JUST the last value, over all rows. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, now getting "ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function".  Here is the exact version I'm trying

SELECT 
  MAX(IF(dates.avg_price>0, dates.`date`, '0001-01-01')) AS avg_date,
  MAX(IF(dates.foil_avg_price>0, dates.`date`, '0001-01-01')) AS foil_avg_date,
  price.avg_price, foilprice.foil_avg_price
FROM
  card_price AS dates
  INNER JOIN card_price AS price
    ON MAX(IF(dates.avg_price>0, dates.`date`, '0001-01-01'))=price.`date`
  INNER JOIN card_price AS foilprice
    ON MAX(IF(dates.foil_avg_price>0, dates.`date`, '0001-01-01'))=foilprice.`date`
GROUP BY dates.card_id;

Comment: Edited again - strange to see, that the parser won't resolve the other version (join on a caclualted fiedl)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.card_id, a.avg_date, a.avg_price, b.foil_date, b.foil_avg_price
FROM (SELECT c.card_id, c.date AS avg_date, c.avg_price  
      FROM cards c 
      INNER JOIN (SELECT c.card_id, MAX(IF(c.avg_price > 0, c.date, NULL)) avg_date 
                  FROM cards c GROUP BY c.card_id
                ) a ON c.card_id = a.card_id AND c.date = a.avg_date 
     ) AS a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.card_id, c.date AS foil_date, c.foil_avg_price  
           FROM cards c 
           INNER JOIN (SELECT c.card_id, MAX(IF(c.foil_avg_price > 0, c.date, NULL)) foil_date 
                       FROM cards c GROUP BY c.card_id
                     ) a ON c.card_id = a.card_id AND c.date = a.foil_date
         ) AS b ON a.card_id = b.card_id ;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT a.card_id, a.avg_date, a.avg_price, b.foil_date, b.foil_avg_price
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT c.card_id, c.date, c.avg_price 
            FROM cards c WHERE c.avg_price > 0 
            ORDER BY c.date DESC
          ) AS A 
      GROUP BY A.date
     ) AS a 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * 
            FROM (SELECT c.card_id, c.date, c.foil_avg_price 
                  FROM cards c WHERE c.foil_avg_price > 0 
                  ORDER BY c.date DESC
                ) AS B 
            GROUP BY B.date
          ) AS b ON a.card_id = b.card_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT A.card_id,max(date),MAX(avg_price), (SELECT MAX(date) FROM test WHERE card_id = A.card_id AND foil_avg_price = MAX(A.foil_avg_price)) AS date,MAX(foil_avg_price) FROM test A
```

GROUP BY A.card_id

Answer (score 0):

How about if you had 20,000,000 rows...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(card_id INT NOT NULL
,date DATETIME NOT NULL               
,price_type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,price_value DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(card_id,date,price_type)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(10000,'2014-06-28 09:05:56','avg_price',5.02),
(20000,'2014-06-28 09:05:54','avg_price',14.58),
(10000,'2014-06-29 09:05:56','avg_price',0.00),
(20000,'2014-06-29 09:05:54','avg_price',14.58),
(10000,'2014-07-01 09:05:56','avg_price',0.00),
(20000,'2014-07-01 09:05:54','avg_price',0.00),
(10000,'2014-06-28 09:05:56','foil_avg_price',10.22),
(20000,'2014-06-28 09:05:54','foil_avg_price',25.10),
(10000,'2014-06-29 09:05:56','foil_avg_price',19.62),
(20000,'2014-06-29 09:05:54','foil_avg_price',0.00),
(10000,'2014-07-01 09:05:56','foil_avg_price',19.62),
(20000,'2014-07-01 09:05:54','foil_avg_price',25.10);

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT card_id,price_type,MAX(date) max_date FROM my_table WHERE price_value > 0 GROUP BY card_id,price_type) y
    ON y.card_id = x.card_id 
   AND y.price_type = x.price_type 
   AND y.max_date = x.date;
+---------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| card_id | date                | price_type     | price_value |
+---------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
|   10000 | 2014-06-28 09:05:56 | avg_price      |        5.02 |
|   10000 | 2014-07-01 09:05:56 | foil_avg_price |       19.62 |
|   20000 | 2014-06-29 09:05:54 | avg_price      |       14.58 |
|   20000 | 2014-07-01 09:05:54 | foil_avg_price |       25.10 |
+---------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
```